# Register a user with php and adding email into mailchimp list

Tags: php, html, ajax, database, mailchimp

Today we are adding users to our system with only an email address. I have created the front end.html pages but not the `.php` files. What I know regarding these are that they add the user in to an MySQL database, the user then receives an email confirmation.

We are now redesigning our webpage where we want the current registration functionality in addition to adding these emails into a mailchimp subscription list.

The Mailchimp code works where users are added to the list, and the PHP code works where users are added to the database, but they do not work together.

When the code is like below only the Mailchimp part works, it never posts to `registration_process.php`. If I remove the mailchimp class, the user is added to DB.

How can I easily add users to DB trough `registration_process.php` and to Mailchimp list?

```js
$('.mailchimp').ajaxChimp({
    callback: mailchimpCallback,
    url: "USER LIST URL HERE"
});

function mailchimpCallback(resp) {
     if (resp.result === 'success') {
      $('.subscription-success').html('<i class="icon_check_alt2"></i><br/>' + resp.msg).fadeIn(1000);
      $('.subscription-error').fadeOut(500);
      $('#form').submit();

    } else if(resp.result === 'error') {
      $('.subscription-error').html('<i class="icon_close_alt2"></i><br/>' + resp.msg).fadeIn(1000);
    }
 }
```

```html
<form class="subscription-form form-inline mailchimp" method="post" name="form" id="form" action="registration_process.php"  data-wow-offset="10" data-wow-duration="1.5s" >

<!-- EMAIL INPUT BOX -->
<input type="email" name="email" id="email" placeholder="Din e-post" class="form-control input-box" required>

<!-- SUBSCRIBE BUTTON -->
<button type="submit" name="submit" id="register" class="btn btn-default standard-button">Registrer nå!</button>

</form>
```

Comment: Is the mailchimp code located on `registration_process.php` ?

Comment: No it is in a different file: `code`if ( isset($_POST['email']) && filter_var($_POST['email'], FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL) ) {
      
      $e_mail = $_POST['email'] . "," . "\n";
   file_put_contents('email-list.txt', $e_mail, FILE_APPEND | LOCK_EX);

}`code`

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the mailchimp ajax code cancels the default form submission and makes an ajax call instead.

There are several ways around this like making 2 ajax calls, the one to mailchimp and another one to your own server or you could try submitting the form in the `mailchimpCallback` function by adding this to the end of it:

```
$('#form').submit();
```

That way the form will be submitted in the normal / non-ajax way as soon as the mailchimp ajax call is done.

Comment: In my mind this should work as well, but it does not. Only the mailchimp part is submitted. I will try to make 2 ajax calls.

Comment: @MatsØverland What does `mailchimpCallback` look like, can you add it to your question?

Comment: the function has been added to the question

Answer (score 0):

If you're already running php on the backend, it will be far easier to just make an API call at that time rather than trying to rig two forms together.